# Java app bundle for Mac not processing arguments

Tags: java, macos, javafx, ant, bundle

I am updating a legacy Java app to so that it runs with Java 8. I am using ant and JavaFX. This app requires a set of arguments. I have specified the arguments with  and they appear in the generated cfg file, however, they are not processed when the app is launched by clicking on the icon. The arguments are processed when the app is started via the command line.

ant script:

```
<project name="xxxxxx" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

  <property name="JAVA_HOME" value="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home"/>

  <echo message="JAVA_HOME: ${JAVA_HOME}" />

  <property name="build.src.dir" value="src"/>
  <property name="build.classes.dir" value="classes"/>
  <property name="build.dist.dir" value="dist"/>
  <property name="build.java.resources.dir" value="../Contents/Java"/>

  <target name="default">

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml" uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpath="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>

    <fx:application id="xxxxxx" name="xxxxxx" mainClass="com.xxxx">
          <fx:argument>-application com.xxxxx.Application -image xxxxxx/splashscreen.jpg -background black -title xxxxx -dock_icon ../application.icns -mem_max 1024</fx:argument>
    </fx:application>

    <fx:resources id="appRes">
          <fx:fileset dir="${build.dist.dir}" includes="Startup.jar"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:jar destfile="${build.dist.dir}/Startup.jar">
          <fx:application refid="xxxxxxx"/>
          <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
          <fx:fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    </fx:jar>

    <fx:deploy width="300" height="250"
           outdir="./deploy" embedJNLP="false"
           outfile="xxxxxxx"
           signBundle="false"
           nativeBundles="all">

           <fx:application refId="xxxx"/>

           <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

           <fx:info title="xxxxx" vendor="xxx"/>
    </fx:deploy>
   </target>
 </project>
```

Generated cfg:

```
[Application]
app.name=xxxxx
app.mainjar=Startup.jar
app.version=1.0
app.preferences.id=xxxx
app.mainclass=com/xxxx/SplashScreen
app.classpath=
app.runtime=$APPDIR/PlugIns/Java.runtime
app.identifier=xxxx

[JVMOptions]

[JVMUserOptions]

[ArgOptions]
-application com.xxx.Application -image com/xxx/splashscreen.jpg -background black -title xxxx -dock_icon ../application.icns -mem_max 1024
```

Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each argument needs to be specified separately, as such:

```
    <fx:argument>-application</fx:argument>
    <fx:argument>com.xxxx.Application</fx:argument>
    <fx:argument>-image</fx:argument> 
    <fx:argument>com/xxxx/splashscreen.jpg</fx:argument>
```